# Why can the keyword "weak" only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types

Tags: swift, variables, weak-references

When I'm declaring variables as `weak` in Swift, I sometimes get the error message from Xcode:

> 'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types

or

> 'weak' must not be applied to non-class-bound 'SomeProtocol'; consider adding a protocol conformance that has a class bound

I'm wondering why the keyword `weak` can only applied to class and class-bound protocol types? What is the reason behind this requirement?

Comment: `weak` is only relevant to reference counting and only classes are reference counted

Answer (score 86, accepted):

`weak` is a qualifier for reference types (as opposed to value types, such as `struct`s and built-in value types).

Reference types let you have multiple references to the same object. The object gets deallocated when the last strong reference stops referencing it (weak references do not count).

Value types, on the other hand, are assigned by copy. Reference counting does not apply, so `weak` modifier does not make sense with them.

Answer (score 139):

One common reason for this error is that you have declared you own protocol, but forgot to inherit from `AnyObject`:

```
protocol PenguinDelegate: AnyObject {
    func userDidTapThePenguin()
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: PenguinDelegate?
}
```

The code above will give you the error if you forget to inherit from `AnyObject`. The reason being that `weak` only makes sense for reference types (classes). So you make the compiler less nervous by clearly stating that the PenguinDelegate is intended for classes, and not value types.

Comment: what is the advantage of inheriting from NSObjectProtocol? My own delegates don't do that and I haven't encountered any problem in my uses

Comment: @Apostolos  Weak references are only valid in classes.  By inheriting from NSObjectProtocol your are guaranteeing to the compiler that the protocol will only be used for classes (and not for enums, etc.).

Comment: @VinceO'Sullivan What's the advantage of guaranteeing that to the compiler? Isn't is easier to just not inherit from `NSObjectProtocol`? For one you don't have to deal with adding the `weak` modifier.

Comment: Yep, it works. But you don't know why. `weak` is a qualifier for reference types, it makes no sense with value types because value types cannot be weak by definition. A protocol can be adopted by reference types *and* value types. So you should constrain it to be implemented *only* by reference types: `protocol PenguinDelegate: class { }`
Here, you are constraining the protocol to be implemented only by `NSObjectProtocol`s, whose are reference types too, that's the reason why it works.

Comment: Use `protocol PenguinDelegate: class` which does not depend on an Objective-C runtime but still solves the problem.

Answer (score 65):

```
protocol PenguinDelegate: class {
    func userDidTapThePenguin()
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: PenguinDelegate?
}
```

If you type class after your protocol it works as well and seems more appropriate that for NSObjectProtocol.

Comment: I feel like the combination of this and the answer from @dasblinkenlight would fully answer this question. dasblinkenlight explained why the error message is showing and this explains how to achieve what you were likely trying to do as a developer.

Answer (score 13):

Well just in case anyone else thinks that you have everything correct in your code like me, check that you did not mistakenly replaced the `:` by an `=`.

Here is what I had. It was also giving me the same error as above:

```
protocol PenguinDelegate: class {
    func userDidTapThePenguin()
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate = PenguinDelegate?
}
```

But the correct way is:

```
protocol PenguinDelegate: class {
    func userDidTapThePenguin()
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: PenguinDelegate?
}
```

Do you see the difference? It took me a while to see that I had an equal sign instead of a colon. Also note that I did get other errors for the same line for I had decided my first error seem like the most likely to be the real problem :

> -`weak` may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types

:-<

Answer (score 5):

I find out in one case where you even have class type but still you get this error message.

For example,

```
class MyVC: UIViewController {
   var myText: UITextView = {
      [weak self]
      let text = UITextView()
      // some codes using self
      return text
   }()
}
```

Here an `UITextView` object is returned from an anonymous block as initialization of `var myText`. I got the same type of error message. To resolve the issue, the `var` has to be marked as `lazy`:

```
class MyVC: UIViewController {
   lasy var myText: UITextView = {
      [weak self]
      let text = UITextView()
      // some codes using self
      return text
   }()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just FYI and who is not updated.
After swift proposal SE-0156 https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0156-subclass-existentials.md was implemented, there is in the Swift docs "Class-Only Protocols section" https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html#ID281 now described to **use AnyObject instead of class**.
So, it is possible for *: class* to be deprecated in future.

Answer (score 2):

`weak` is for ARC(Automatic Reference Counting). It means not adding reference count. So it only works for `Class`. And in Swift, you will get optional value for security.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to capture String and Array-typed properties for a closure. I got these errors:

> 'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not '[String]'
>
> 'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not 'String'

I played a while in the playground, and it turned out, capturing self is enough for these types.

Answer (score 1):

[image]I was using objective C class in swift for a scrolView. I created IBOutlet of that scroll view. And while compiling code this error started showing.

So to fix this kind of issue, import that class in your bridging header

> ## import "YourClass.h"

I was using Xcode 9.2 with swift 3.2

Answer (score 0):

`weak` only works for reference type, so Xcode would report an error if you are calling from `struct` (instead of `class`).

Comment: well, if closures are reference types, then why XCode shows an error `'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not '() -> Void'`?

Answer (score 0):

1. weak is not for value type.
2. weak comes to the picture only for the class.

"weak" can apply anything which is inherited from class or class-bound protocol types

1. Class Protocol:
   protocol ViewControllerDelegate : class {
       func getInformationk(value: String?) }
2. NSObjectProtocol:

   protocol ViewControllerDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {
       func getInformation(value: String?) }

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?