# Swift3 Call function in parent out of function in child view

Tags: swift, swift3, parent-child, superview

I have a child UIView class instantiated in an UIViewController, the UIViewController has a function called sigIn(){}. I need to call this function from within UIView.

I tried somehow using the self.superview and casting it into a UIViewController but this did not work. I found a method where you use a listener to detect the trigger but I think this is not a good solution. Is there anther simple way of accessing functions in the paren view form the subview ?

```
class SignUIView: UIView {
  func signInUIButtonH(sender: UIButton) {

    ("Call parent signIn() function")

  }

  (init etc. ...)
}
```

Comment: Please post the code of the function of the UIView which calls `signIn()`? Usually you use the delegate or target-action pattern so you don't need to care about who is your parent.

Comment: I saw one delegate solutions but it was in C and I did not understand how it worked.

Comment: So you want to call UIView method from your UIViewController Right?

Comment: yes, that is what I want to do

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly, [View and a View Controller are two different concepts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31814563/whats-the-difference-between-a-view-and-a-viewcontroller). `.superview` will not give you a View Controller, and casting it will only crash the program.

While [it is possible to find out the current View Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667009/get-top-most-uiviewcontroller), it is very unidiomatic in your use case because you cannot be sure that View Controller has the `signIn()` function, and you can't even ensure the "current View Controller" is the View Controller of the view.

---

iOS typically use the ["delegate pattern"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40501780/examples-of-delegates-in-swift-3) instead. In your case, first you define a **protocol** for the `signIn()` function:

```
protocol SignInDelegate {
    func signIn()
}
```

Then, the View needs to provide a variable of this protocol. This variable is called the **delegate**. Whenever we want to sign in, just call the delegate's `signIn()` function.

The variable should be a weak reference to [avoid strong reference cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056526/swift-delegation-when-to-use-weak-pointer-on-delegate). The protocol also [needs to be class-bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38841127/why-can-the-keyword-weak-only-be-applied-to-class-and-class-bound-protocol-typ), otherwise the compiler will complain.

```
protocol SignInDelegate: class {    // <-- needs :class for weak
    func signIn()
}

class SignUIView: UIView {
    weak var delegate: SignInDelegate?    // <-- delegate

    func signInUIButtonH(sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.signIn()    // <-- call the delegate
    }
}
```

Next we adapt the protocol to the View Controller:

```
class SignInViewController: UIViewController, SignInDelegate {   // <-- adapt the protocol
    func signIn() {    // <-- implement the function
        print("sign in")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        signInView.delegate = self    // <-- tell the subview we will be the delegate.
    }
}
```

---

We usually expose this delegate to Interface Builder so we could simply connect the View to the View Controller to assign the delegate.

[image]

This is done by [adding `@IBOutlet`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643007/iboutlet-and-ibaction) to the delegate field. Unfortunately, [Xcode only recognizes `AnyObject`/`NSObject` for IBOutlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180268/interface-builder-iboutlet-and-protocols-for-delegate-and-datasource-in-swift) which defeats the whole purpose of using the delegate pattern for type-safety. So we need to introduce some ugly hack to workaround it for IB. The protocol now also needs `@objc` because resolving these IB connections requires the Objective-C runtime.

```
@objc protocol SignInDelegate {   // <-- needs @objc for IB (:class is implied by @objc)
    func signIn()
}

class SignUIView {
    // Blame Xcode for this mess. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42227800/224671
    #if TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER
    @IBOutlet weak var delegate: AnyObject?
    #else
    weak var delegate: SignInDelegate?
    #endif

    func signInUIButtonH(sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.signIn()
    }
}

class SignInViewController: UIViewController, SignInDelegate {   // <-- adapt the protocol
    func signIn() {    // <-- implement the function
        print("sign in")
    }
    // Note: no need to set signInView.delegate manually.
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation, that works perfectly XD

Comment: I would say "Next, we make the ViewController adopt (or conform to) the protocol", not "Next we adapt the protocol to the View Controller:", but it's a detail

Answer (score 0):

Declare a protocol for the `signIn()` function and let the parent ViewController conform to that protocol. Then make the parent ViewController the delegate of `SignUIView`:

```
protocol SignInProtocol {
    func signIn()
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController, SignInProtocol {
    var signUIView: SignUIView

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.signUIView = SignUIView()
        self.signUIView.delegate = self  // set the delegate
    }


    func signIn() {
        ...
    }
}


class SignUIView: UIView {
  var delegate: SignProtocol?   // the delegate

  func signInUIButtonH(sender: UIButton) {
    // call the delegate
    self.delegate?.signIn()
  }

  (init etc. ...)
}
```

Comment: where you have "set the delegate" It throws the error that "Cannot assign value of type "MyViewController' to type 'SignInProtocol?'"

Comment: You need to set the `SignInProtocol` declaration on the ViewController: `class MyViewController: UIViewController, SignInProtocol`