# Prevent memory leak in tap recognizer

Tags: swift, swift3, memory-leaks, xcode8

//  I get a memory leak on this code. Any ideas? (I think it is connected to the tapRecognizer)

```
func paletteTapped( _ tapRecognizer : UITapGestureRecognizer )
{
    if tapRecognizer.state == .ended {
        let touch = tapRecognizer.location( in: self )
        if let color = colorForTouch(touch) {
            self.delegate?.selectPaletteColor(color)
        }
        fadeOut()
    }
}
```

Comment: How is `delegate` referenced? Delegates should almost always be `weak` references

Comment: And don't forget to inherit your protocol from `NSObjectProtocol` or `class` , when making the reference `weak` [link for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40194512/5722895)

Comment: weak var delegate : PaletteDelegate?
and  protocol PaletteDelegate : class {
    // delegates the selected color on a tap event
    func selectPaletteColor( _ color : UIColor )
}